# Loading a list of controllers dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, controller

I can't get my head wrapped around solving the following problem using angularJS.

I have a list view containing different kinds of data elements. Each element in itself is a view and has its own controller.

Now I want to iterate over this `Array` of the data items and based on `recordType` attribute, I want to initialize a controller with a template and finally add it to the list view.

At the moment I am using `ng-include="item.recordType+'.html'"` to dynamically load the template and the template itself has an `ng-controller` tag which loads the relevant controller. But I am not sure if this is the best approach.

```
<div class="data-item" ng-repeat="item in container.record_collection">
    <div ng-include src="item.tRecordType + '.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Say record-type is `apples`

```
<script id="apples.html" type="text/ng-template">
   <div ng-controller="ApplesController as apple">
       <!-- ... HTML TEMPLATE ...  -->
   </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Could you show us your code? Since your items are repeated I'd think about creating a directive.

Comment: @kabamaru The directive would also work like ng-include wouldn't it ? Btw which part of the code would be required since the app is humongous.

Comment: Yes exactly you could 'append' as many directives dynamically as you like, but this again might not worth the trouble if you are not using these pieces of code again and again. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/uWmULMzDBTA/DJjnyL4EKT0J. 
But what's the problem you are having?

Comment: I just want to know the best practice.

Comment: Well if you want my opinion the ng-include is fine. I'd consider the use of a directive under two circumstances. When the piece of code was used again and again or if for some reason a private scope is needed.